# Python: Gunicorn - using SSL cerficate error

Tags: python, ssl, gunicorn

I have written Gunicorn REST backend for my webpage. I want to use HTTPS, since I am sending sensitive informations. I have added all the certs to the starup of gunicorn. However sometimes I get this error:

```
[SSL: TLSV1_ALERT_UNKNOWN_CA] tlsv1 alert unknown ca (_ssl.c:1750)
[2015-10-21 21:44:33 +0000] [20490] [ERROR] Error handling request
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gunicorn/workers/sync.py", line 129, in handle
    req = six.next(parser)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gunicorn/http/parser.py", line 41, in __next__
    self.mesg = self.mesg_class(self.cfg, self.unreader, self.req_count)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gunicorn/http/message.py", line 153, in __init__
    super(Request, self).__init__(cfg, unreader)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gunicorn/http/message.py", line 53, in __init__
    unused = self.parse(self.unreader)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gunicorn/http/message.py", line 165, in parse
    self.get_data(unreader, buf, stop=True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gunicorn/http/message.py", line 156, in get_data
    data = unreader.read()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gunicorn/http/unreader.py", line 38, in read
    d = self.chunk()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gunicorn/http/unreader.py", line 65, in chunk
    return self.sock.recv(self.mxchunk)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ssl.py", line 714, in recv
    return self.read(buflen)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ssl.py", line 608, in read
    v = self._sslobj.read(len or 1024)
SSLError: [SSL: SSL_HANDSHAKE_FAILURE] ssl handshake failure (_ssl.c:1750)
```

I have no idea what to do about it. I also tried to google the problem, however no solution was helpful. The error is weird. Apache is running fine with the exactly same certificates and error occurs randomly.

Could you help me?

Comment: I haven't found out the python solution, however I stopped using gunicorn with SSL and setup Apache proxy instead.